# What parameters for lightweight HTML5 video with avconv?

Tags: vlc-media-player, mp4, libav

I have this:

```
avconv version 0.8.16-6:0.8.16-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
built on Sep 16 2014 23:10:48 with gcc 4.7.2

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'film.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2013-07-09 17:41:04
  Duration: 00:00:15.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6132 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9],                                                               5951 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-07-09 17:41:04
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 189 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-07-09 17:41:04
```

and want to down quality to standard PAL - how to do with ffmpeg/avconv?

As a result I want mp4/webm/ogg - something html5 compliant - but as light as possible (that's why I downscalling into PAL)

Comment: Do you need the exact resolution specified by PAL? Or just something smaller? And when you say "as light as possible", wouldn't you just rather want to reduce the bitrate?

Comment: Again, please include the complete console output so we know what version of `ffmpeg` you are using and what its capabilities are.

Comment: I think that PAL is the lowest acceptable resolution, because content would be played on 42" TV

Comment: On a 42" TV, PAL would look quite bad. But it depends on your application. Is it Internet streaming?  Have you already tried resizing the video?

Comment: Yes, but i'm confused with parameters. When I take some two pass example with 640x380 it looks much better than 800x600 which i made  from mp4 - with just scalling

Comment: Well, you also have to set the quality or bitrate when re-encoding a video. Have you done that? See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 (please mention me with @slhck, otherwise I will not get a reply). Can you include the commandline output of those two processes?

Comment: @slhck you're right - the two pass example from web has lots of parameters but I just take first of google search example, copy&paste and got good looking avi. But i'm sure, that parameters doesn't prepared for my needs (it would be very lucky shot) - If you ask about bitrate/quality - i definitely doesn't know what bitrate would be just fine - I expect advice - "take 128k bitrate - and check if it satisfy your needs" - and than I would take 2x and 0x5 of 128k to check if i could go better or hardware force me to change of expectations. But there're to many of variables for first guess.

Comment: Please see the linked (duplicate) question. It explains what commands you have to run for MP4/WebM/Ogg video compatible with HTML5. I would suggest that you *do not* resize the video. 720p is quite acceptable and I wouldn't go lower on a big TV. Rather reduce the bitrate to about 1 MBit/s by setting `-b:v 1M` as parameter.

Comment: This is exactly what i want.. Now i see, that good subject of question is priceless ;D Than you @slhck